# Retorna valor numerico en un inputText

Tags: javascript, html

Quisiera lograr que el input donde muestre el total no retorne un valor NaN cuando este no encuentre otro valor numerico en los otros inputText. Probe con la funcion isNaN, pero aun asi, no logre que me diera el resultado que esperaba, puede que lo utilice mal. El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<form name="f">
<p>cantidad: <input type="text" id="n1" name="num1" value="0" onchange="cal()" onkeyup="cal()" /></p>
    <p>precio: <input type="text" id="n2" name="num2" value="0" onchange="cal()" onkeyup="cal()" /></p>
    <p>Total: <input type="text" id="n3" name="total" value="0" onchange="cal()" onkeyup="cal()"/></p>
    </form>


    <script>
        function cal() {
          var a = parseInt(document.f.num1.value)
          var b = parseFloat(document.f.num2.value)
          var c = parseInt(document.f.total.value)
        
            try {
                document.f.total.value = (new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", { style: "currency", currency: "USD" }).format(a * b));
              } catch (e) {
              }
            }
    </script>
```

Espero que entiendan y gracias por su atencion.

Answer (score 1):

podrías intentarlo cambiando el tipo de input de num1 y num2 a number, de tal modo que quedara así el código:

espero que te funcione. Saludos

```
<form name="f">
<p>cantidad: <input type="number" id="n1" name="num1" value="0" onchange="cal()" onkeyup="cal()" /></p>
    <p>precio: <input type="number" id="n2" name="num2" value="0" onchange="cal()" onkeyup="cal()" /></p>
    <p>Total: <input type="text" id="n3" name="total" value="0" onchange="cal()" onkeyup="cal()"/></p>
    </form>


    <script>
        function cal() {
          var a = (document.f.num1.value)
          var b = (document.f.num2.value)
          var c = (document.f.total.value)
        
            try {
                document.f.total.value = (new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", { style: "currency", currency: "USD" }).format(a * b));
              } catch (e) {
              }
            }
    </script>
```